# Nesting RelativeLayouts within LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to achieve the following layout in Android with the main heading at the top and three subheadings spaced equally apart below, with some buttons below that:

[image]

I was able to accomplish this with the following XML, but I feel like I am not using the RelativeLayout and LinearLayout properly:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cfff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="80sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight=".5">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_caption1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Subheading"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_number1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/text_caption1"
                android:text="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="80sp"
                android:gravity="center"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_caption2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Subheading"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_number2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/text_caption2"
                android:text="10"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="80sp"
                android:gravity="center"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_caption3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Subheading"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_sets"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/text_caption3"
                android:text="3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="80sp"
                android:gravity="center"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Button1 -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <!-- Button2 -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm focusing somewhat on the Subheading portion, although any suggestions on the overall layout would be welcome. So I used 3 different RelativeLayouts to put the "Subheading" captions with their respective numbers, and nested those within a horizontal LinearLayout to get them spaced next to each other horizontally.

This seems to be creating a bit of a problem, since Android Studio is complaining that my use of layout_weight within nested layouts is bad for performance. When I get rid of the layout_weight however, everything falls apart and I only see the "Title" and one subheading. I'm also wondering whether I could have accomplished this more elegantly with just one RelativeLayout and no nesting, but I can't see how to code something like this without the use of a LinearLayout.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,you can  accomplish this more elegantly with just one RelativeLayout and no nesting
I hope this is what you are looking for

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cfff"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="80sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_caption1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/text_number1"
        android:text="Subheading"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_number1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="80sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_caption2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/text_number2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Subheading"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_number2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="80sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_caption3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/text_number3"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Subheading"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_number3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="80sp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty much what I was looking for. I'm curious though, is it possible to have the Subheadings all center-justified? The right and left side are hugging the left and right pane in this XML, and I can move them with padding, but not sure how else to achieve that look.

Comment: To clarify, I mean center-justifying the Subheadings and numbers within their respective columns (left, center, right).

Answer (score 1):

try this one...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="10">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:text="TITLE"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="45sp"
    android:id="@+id/textView64" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:weightSum="10">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="3.25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Subheading"
            android:id="@+id/textView66" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:id="@+id/textView67" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SubHeading"
            android:id="@+id/textView68" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:id="@+id/textView69" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="3.25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SubHeading"
            android:id="@+id/textView70" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:id="@+id/textView71" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    />
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem about layout_weight, but I am curious as to whether this is possible with RelativeLayout instead of nested LinearLayouts.

Comment: based on suitation.But one think you need to remember relativelayout doesn't have weightsum so inner views of relative layout cannot have layout weight porperties.If you want to use layout weight to all your child views you need to use linearlayout.

Answer (score 1):

Change  `android:weightSum` and `android:layout_weight` acoording to your required ratio...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#cfff"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:weightSum="4">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textSize="80sp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_caption1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Subheading"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_number1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/text_caption1"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_caption2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Subheading"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_number2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/text_caption2"
            android:text="10"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_caption3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Subheading"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_sets"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/text_caption3"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Button1 -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button1"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<!-- Button2 -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:text="Button2"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```